# React Native image fades with signed URL (google cloud storage)

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage

I'm persisting user profile with asyncStorage. When I request the user information from backend it responds with different avatar url but same image. And react native re renders the image component maybe because url is different. And it causes to image fade out fade in effect.

Here's demonstation:

```
export default _ => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({}) 

  React.useEffect(_ => {

    _getUser()

  }, [])

  _getUser = async _ =>
  {
    const saved = await AsyncStorage('user')
    if (saved)
      setUser(JSON.parse(saved))

    _fetchUser()
  }


  _fetchUser = async _ =>
  {
    const response = await fetch()
    setUser(response)

    await AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response))
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={{uri: user.avatar}} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

So, how can I prevent re render or fade in/out effect?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to add else condition:

```js
 _getUser = async _ =>
  {
    const saved = await AsyncStorage('user')
    if (saved) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(saved))
    } else {
      _fetchUser()
    }
  }
```

Comment: some user informations could have been updated. AsyncStorage is only for persistance (offline mode or slow internet)